# How to create new variables based on a binary variable in a grouped data set in R?

Tags: r, rolling-computation

The data set has 3 columns-the 1st column is "id", the 2nd column is "year", and the 3rd column is "node". The 3rd column is a binary variable. Now, we need to fix the data errors on the column 3 "node" with the rule as follows.

1)Within each id, all values before the last value of node=1 should be equal to 1. There should be no node=0 occurring before a node=1. It should only stay at node=1 for all years or go from node=1 to node=0 at some point.

2)within each id, if all values of node from year1 to year8 equals (0 or 1), then we must keep them without any change.

To sum, the corrected data set should look like this,

```
 id     node   year
383100111   1   1
383100111   1   2
383100111   1   3
383100111   1   4
383100111   1   5
383100111   1   6
383100111   1   7
383100111   0   8
383100222   1   1
383100222   1   2
383100222   1   3
383100222   1   4
383100222   1   5
383100222   1   6
383100222   1   7
383100222   1   8
383100333   1   1
383100333   1   2
383100333   1   3
383100333   1   4
383100333   1   5
383100333   1   6
383100333   1   7
383100333   1   8
383100444   1   1
383100444   1   2
383100444   1   3
383100444   1   4
383100444   1   5
383100444   1   6
383100444   1   7
383100444   0   8
383100555   1   1
383100555   1   2
383100555   1   3
383100555   1   4
383100555   1   5
383100555   1   6
383100555   1   7
383100555   1   8
383100666   0   1
383100666   0   2
383100666   0   3
383100666   0   4
383100666   0   5
383100666   0   6
383100666   0   7
383100666   0   8
383100777   1   1
383100777   1   2
383100777   1   3
383100777   1   4
383100777   1   5
383100777   1   6
383100777   1   7
383100777   1   8
```

The original data set with errors is structured as follows,

```
structure(list(id = c(383100111, 383100111, 383100111, 383100111, 
383100111, 383100111, 383100111, 383100111, 383100222, 383100222, 
383100222, 383100222, 383100222, 383100222, 383100222, 383100222, 
383100333, 383100333, 383100333, 383100333, 383100333, 383100333, 
383100333, 383100333, 383100444, 383100444, 383100444, 383100444, 
383100444, 383100444, 383100444, 383100444, 383100555, 383100555, 
383100555, 383100555, 383100555, 383100555, 383100555, 383100555, 
383100666, 383100666, 383100666, 383100666, 383100666, 383100666, 
383100666, 383100666, 383100777, 383100777, 383100777, 383100777, 
383100777, 383100777, 383100777, 383100777), node = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), year = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 56L), class ="data.frame")->dataframe
```

Thank you!

Comment: I could see some contradictions between the conditions you specified and the output that is being shown. Can you check once again? Let me know, if I had missed something.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have made the changes to the typo.

Comment: Please also clarify in case of sequence 1,0,1 whether it should be changed to 1,1,1 or 1,0,0?

Comment: it should be changed to 1,1,1.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
library(tidyverse)
df_repaired <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(col1 = cumsum(node)) %>%
  mutate(node2 = ifelse(last(col1)==col1 & node == 0, 0, 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-col1, -node) %>%
  rename(node = node2)

> df_repaired
# A tibble: 56 x 3
          id  year  node
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 383100111     1     1
 2 383100111     2     1
 3 383100111     3     1
 4 383100111     4     1
 5 383100111     5     1
 6 383100111     6     1
 7 383100111     7     1
 8 383100111     8     0
 9 383100222     1     1
10 383100222     2     1
# ... with 46 more rows
```

Methodology explained:

1. Cumulative summation on field `node`. For this `cumsum()` has been used
2. checking when cumulative sum stopped increasing further.  This was checked with `ifelse` conditional statement using `last` value in each group.  In order to rule out the last 1 in node, this was also included as a condition with `&` operator.

To further explain the things let's take code without deleting dummy columns created..

```
df_repaired <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(col1 = cumsum(node)) %>%
  mutate(node2 = ifelse(last(col1)==col1 & node == 0, 0, 1)) %>%
  ungroup()

> print(df_repaired, n=56)
# A tibble: 56 x 5
          id  node  year  col1 node2
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 383100111     1     1     1     1
 2 383100111     1     2     2     1
 3 383100111     1     3     3     1
 4 383100111     0     4     3     1
 5 383100111     1     5     4     1
 6 383100111     0     6     4     1
 7 383100111     1     7     5     1
 8 383100111     0     8     5     0
 9 383100222     0     1     0     1
10 383100222     1     2     1     1
11 383100222     0     3     1     1
12 383100222     1     4     2     1
13 383100222     0     5     2     1
14 383100222     0     6     2     1
15 383100222     1     7     3     1
16 383100222     1     8     4     1
17 383100333     1     1     1     1
18 383100333     0     2     1     1
19 383100333     0     3     1     1
20 383100333     0     4     1     1
21 383100333     1     5     2     1
22 383100333     1     6     3     1
23 383100333     0     7     3     1
24 383100333     1     8     4     1
25 383100444     0     1     0     1
26 383100444     0     2     0     1
27 383100444     1     3     1     1
28 383100444     1     4     2     1
29 383100444     0     5     2     1
30 383100444     1     6     3     1
31 383100444     1     7     4     1
32 383100444     0     8     4     0
33 383100555     1     1     1     1
34 383100555     0     2     1     1
35 383100555     1     3     2     1
36 383100555     1     4     3     1
37 383100555     1     5     4     1
38 383100555     1     6     5     1
39 383100555     0     7     5     1
40 383100555     1     8     6     1
41 383100666     0     1     0     0
42 383100666     0     2     0     0
43 383100666     0     3     0     0
44 383100666     0     4     0     0
45 383100666     0     5     0     0
46 383100666     0     6     0     0
47 383100666     0     7     0     0
48 383100666     0     8     0     0
49 383100777     1     1     1     1
50 383100777     1     2     2     1
51 383100777     1     3     3     1
52 383100777     1     4     4     1
53 383100777     1     5     5     1
54 383100777     1     6     6     1
55 383100777     1     7     7     1
56 383100777     1     8     8     1
```

Comment: just 10 observations left?

Comment: I have graded your answer as useful! Could you please explain the purpose of cumsum function here? I really don't fully understand. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I just want to learn and so hope you can clarify the meaning of your code. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my answer with explanation! please see that.  I have used simple logic that `0` when added to some value returns the same value.  This value for every column was checked with last value in that column to make sure that it was the last `0` in that group. For last `0` onwards it was changed to `0` and everything else was changed to `1`.  Did this clarify your doubts?

Comment: I still don't know why you want to use cumsum function.

Comment: Consider a hypothetical example of seq, 1,0,1,0,1,0.  Cumsum will yield 1,1,2,2,3,3.  Last value is 3.  This value 3 occurred in seq at fifth position which gives us last value of 1(last change).  Thus cumsum has been used to deduce the position of last 1 in seq. Consider another example 1,0,0,1,0,0.  This will cumsum to 1,1,1,2,2,2.  Last value is 2 which occurred first time is sequence at fourth position which is actually the last occurrence of 1 in sequence.

Comment: Since you have not accepted the answer, I have posted a different solution which might be easier to understand, as it is built on your logic literally

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy, which may be easier to understand

```
library(tidyverse)

df_repaired <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(dummy_id = row_number(),
         col1 = last(which(node ==1)),
         node2 = ifelse(dummy_id > col1 | is.na(col1), 0, 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-node, -dummy_id, -col1) %>%
  rename(node = node2)

> print(df_repaired, n=56)
# A tibble: 56 x 3
          id  year  node
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 383100111     1     1
 2 383100111     2     1
 3 383100111     3     1
 4 383100111     4     1
 5 383100111     5     1
 6 383100111     6     1
 7 383100111     7     1
 8 383100111     8     0
 9 383100222     1     1
10 383100222     2     1
11 383100222     3     1
12 383100222     4     1
13 383100222     5     1
14 383100222     6     1
15 383100222     7     1
16 383100222     8     1
17 383100333     1     1
18 383100333     2     1
19 383100333     3     1
20 383100333     4     1
21 383100333     5     1
22 383100333     6     1
23 383100333     7     1
24 383100333     8     1
25 383100444     1     1
26 383100444     2     1
27 383100444     3     1
28 383100444     4     1
29 383100444     5     1
30 383100444     6     1
31 383100444     7     1
32 383100444     8     0
33 383100555     1     1
34 383100555     2     1
35 383100555     3     1
36 383100555     4     1
37 383100555     5     1
38 383100555     6     1
39 383100555     7     1
40 383100555     8     1
41 383100666     1     0
42 383100666     2     0
43 383100666     3     0
44 383100666     4     0
45 383100666     5     0
46 383100666     6     0
47 383100666     7     0
48 383100666     8     0
49 383100777     1     1
50 383100777     2     1
51 383100777     3     1
52 383100777     4     1
53 383100777     5     1
54 383100777     6     1
55 383100777     7     1
56 383100777     8     1
```